# What does it mean when there is a comma in the src attribute of a script (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have some legacy code and I can't figure out what this does.

```
<script src="/ajaxpro/xxx.yyy,zzz.ashx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anyone help.  I've searched for a syntax diagram but can't find that.

Comment: It likely means nothing. It's has just been used as part of the filename or URL.

Comment: Commas are valid (though reserved) characters in URIs. This just points to a script with a comma in its filename.

Comment: Yeah, fubar is right, its either a part of a url or a typo.

Comment: Probably a server-side hint to combine multiple files together into one before sending them back combined using some sort of server-side logic

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  I was totally unaware that a comma is valid in a filename.

Comment: Yep, probably ajaxpro developers use that kind of names to organize internally their namespaces and classes

Answer (score 2):

It is just part of the filename.

[Reserved characters and words in filenames(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)